# HttpWebRequiest.AllowAutoRedirect not found in PCL

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

I'm new to Xamarin, so I hope this is not a silly question :)

I am developing a PCL that will function as SDK (NuGet package) for customers to use for their Http APIs.
There's a lot of logic that should be done on both iOS and Android, so I figured PCL is the way to go.
The API I'm wrapping is the HttpWebRequest, basically I expose the exact same API and meddle with the requests before they're being sent.

One of the things I need to do is to ensure all redirections go through me, in order to have cookies control.

I found that the [proper way](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/System.Net.HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect/) to do it is to set:
`HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false`

However when I try to to this, I get an error:
'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'AllowAutoRedirect'...

This is a sample code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PCLTest.Net
{
    public class MyHttpWebRequest
    {
        HttpWebRequest request;

        public bool AllowAutoRedirect
        {
            get
            {
                return request.AllowAutoRedirect;
            }
            set
            {
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I didn't find out why this API is hidden and how to make the framework expose it, but I did end up solving this by reflection like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PCLTest.Net
{
    public class MyHttpWebRequest
    {    
        HttpWebRequest request;

        public bool AllowAutoRedirect
        {
            get
            {
                Type t = request.GetType();
                PropertyInfo pi = t.GetRuntimeProperty("AllowAutoRedirect");
                return (bool)pi.GetValue(request);
            }
            set
            {
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove from PLC target **Windows Phone** (ProjectName->Options->General)

Comment: Nope, that didn't do work. I tried a couple of profiles without Windows phone and it doesn't work. Is there a documentation for which API is included in which profile?